# Cannot drop files onto java apps (having GUIs)

Tags: macos, java, macos-catalina

I have macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) with java installed.

When I open a java-based GUI application (e.g. Axone or Jaikoz), then try to drag/drop a file onto it, nothing happens.

Additionally, when I open a file in Axone (via its File-Open icon-button), it opens in that application ok, but fails to then open that same file in its "partner" Hex Editor application (also based on java).

I mention both issues here in case, taken together, the cause might be suggested.  I wonder if there is/are any macOS security setting I need to change.

Any suggestions how to fix or get diagnostic clues as to what is/isn't causing this would be welcome.

Comment: Drag/drop support in Java GUIs is not automatic, each Java program has to set up support for this.

Comment: Thank you, I will look further into that